# Trying to add lazy constraints to traveling salesman problem

Tags: optimization, combinatorial-optimization, traveling-salesman, c++

For a simple traveling salesman problem, I am trying to add the "miller-tucker-zemlin subtour elimination constraints" by using ILOLAZYCONSTRAINTCALLBACK.

```
ILOLAZYCONSTRAINTCALLBACK3(lazycallback, BoolVarArray2, x, IloNumVarArray, u, IloCplex, tspcplex) {
        IloInt const lokasyon = u.getSize();
    for (IloInt i = 0; i < lokasyon; ++i) {
        for (IloInt j = 0; j < lokasyon; ++j) {
            IloNum ui = getValue(u[i]);
            IloNum xij = getValue(x[i][j]);
            IloNum uj = getValue(u[j]);
            if (ui - uj + lokasyon * xij <= lokasyon - 1) {
                cout << " Adding lazy constraint. i = " << i << " j = " << j << endl;

                add(u[i] - u[j] + lokasyon * x[i][j] <= lokasyon - 1).end();
}}}}
```

I need to getValues of my "decision variables", which are u[i] and x[i][j], to check if the subtour elimination constraints are violated; but cplex fails to solve.

I don't have anything missing with the model, environment, objective function or other constraints.

```
tspcplex.use(lazycallback(tspenv, x, u, tspcplex));
tspcplex.solve();
```

After tspcplex.solve I enter ILOLAZY... but I don't have a solution yet. bool "tspcplex.solve()" is not true so we have an execption thrown at getValue.

What am I missing?

Comment: Note that you should check whether the constraint is *violated*; that is, the if() condition should be > instead of <=.  Also, the lazy approach makes more sense for the DFJ formulation than for the MTZ formulation.

Comment: thanks for the warning. im just trying to get the code running.

Comment: Cross-posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72333102/trying-to-add-lazy-constraints-to-traveling-salesman-problem).

Comment: Exactly what happens when the lazycallback function is executed? Is there an error message?

Comment: bool "tspcplex.solve()" is not true so we have an execption thrown at getValue.

Comment: tspcplex.solve() should not have returned a value yet when you enter the callback. It returns a value only after the solver is done.

Comment: Actually when lazyconstraints are used, tspcplex.solve() returns a solution, which is most likely not feasible to the original model and that solution is checked if the constraints are (if yes, which ones) violated, if yes, adds them to the model. At least that's what is going on in the iloadmipex5.cpp example, which is a demonstration of lazy consrtaints and user cuts. So i need to be able to getValue of the variables at the beginning of LazyCallBack.

Comment: This question is solver-specific and should be tagged as such.

Comment: When I was working with Lazy Constraints in the CPLEX using C++, I had to deal with several tricky stuff, among them I had to add inequalities with the structure LHS >= 0. Also, try to check is your add operation returns any exception: try { add(lhs >= 0).end(); } catch(IloException& e) { cerr << "Exception while adding lazy constraint" << e.getMessage() << "\n"; throw; }. And of course, try to debug your code, for example, run your callback without any piece of code in it, just an empty function, and then try to add operations incrementally in order to see what is causing the bug.